# Hibernate: Dynamic table creation by reading hbm mapping files from a location

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

How to create tables dynamically from hbm files?

My product has multiple clients. For adding a new client, `hbm` mapping file will be given by the client to store the data. (each client having different data and table ).

REST api will be called with the `hbm` file location while adding a new client.

How can hibernate create the tables by reading hbm file dynamically?

Answer (score 0):

Hi this would be a two step process.

1. You need to create **Hibernate Session Factory in runtime** in order to force hibernate to create the table once the hbm file is recieved. You can use the following attribute in the configuration to do that:

   hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto

in the same configuration file you need to reference the incoming file. You can do some template magic or you may be able to add the incoming programmatic as well. You need to check that. You can check this yourself how to do it best, i believe in hibernate 4 you can do it programmaticaly.

2. The second step would be to use Hibernate Dynamic Models http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html_single/#persistent-classes-dynamicmodels
   This is because you would not have the implementation of the entity during runtime.

Answer (score 0):

The sample code to load hbm files dynamically:

```
public class LoadHBMFile {

    private static final SessionFactory session = createSession();

    private static SessionFactory createSession() {
        try {

            SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration()
                    .configure("hibernate.cfg.xml")
                    .addResource("{full path}/demo.hbm.xml")
                    .buildSessionFactory();

            return sessionFactory;

        } catch (Throwable ex) {
            System.out.println("Failed" + ex);
        }
    }

    /* To get the sessionfactory */
    public static SessionFactory getSession() {
        return session;
    }

    /* To close the sessionfactory */
    public static void shutdown() {
        getSession().close();
    }

}
```

Hope this helps :)